# Error File Exists fetching bitbucket repository on Azure

Tags: azure, deployment, bitbucket

Using Azure Bitbucket Deployment on a Linux PHP 5.6 Web App, I've authorized Azure to my account, but when I attempt to sync the app to the repository, it fails and this error (and nothing else) shows in the logs:

```
error: could not lock config file .git/config: File exists\n\n/usr/bin/git config core.autocrlf false
```

This behavior feels like a bug. There weren't really many choices to go wrong in configuring the deployment. What are my options for troubleshooting? How can I correct the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It almost certainly is a bug with Azure and likely due to the way the shared file systems are deployed. I worked around the issue by using Git Push deployments rather than Azure Bitbucket Deployment.